# The formula of computing the Mel-filterbank coefficient

Tags: c++, mfcc

I am working with MFCC in a project about Speech Recognition. According to the document in this website http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/, the formula of computing the Mel-filterbank is as follows:

```
`H (k, m) = 0 if ( k < f[m-1] )   
          = (k - f(m-1)) / (f[m] - f[m-1]) if ( f[m-1] <= k <= f[m] )
          = (f[m+1] - k) / (f[m+1] - f[m]) if ( f[m] <= k <= f[m+1] )
          = 0 if ( k > f[m+1] )`
```

I think something was wrong here. What is "k"? This website isn't the only one. I have search many document and it's still remained. Besides, if m == 1 , f[0] isn't computed, so the condition ( k < f[m-1] ) is wrong, isn't it? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining a function `H` which takes formal arguments `k` and `m`. That's how k is defined. `f[0]` is perfectly well defined.

Basically, the formula describes this form `___/\___` with the peak at `k=f[m]`.